# How to remove Github PAT from Gitlab?

Tags: github, import, gitlab, repository

I recently imported a project from Github to Gitlab (Uni Owned) and I had to put my Github PAT in when importing. Now every-time I select New Project -> Import Project From Github I'm immediately taken to the list of projects on the Github account corresponding to the PAT I put in earlier.

Is there a way I can remove the Github PAT I initially put in so I'm taken to the "Provide your Github PAT" screen instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/github.html#use-a-github-token),

> To use a newer personal access token in imports [...], sign out of your GitLab account and sign in again, or revoke the older personal access token in GitHub.